# Persistent BottomSheet using NestedScrollView, it contains top padding? support-lib 24.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

There are a lot of nice tutorials talking about **BottomSheet** using `NestedScrollView`. But After I try it with my current support library version 24.2.1, it took me few days with no clue about why mine contains top padding.

Here is my Activity's layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <!-- AppBar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout_with_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabPager="@{tabPager}" />

    <!-- Content -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <!-- [START] BottomSheet -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetMain"
        layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet_song"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />
    <!-- [END BottomSheet] -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the BottomSheet's layout `fragment_bottom_sheet_song.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgBottomSheetPlayer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetPlayer"
            layout="@layout/view_bottom_sheet_player_dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:playAction="@{playAction}"
            app:playObject="@{playSong}" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContent"
            layout="@layout/view_action_detail_song"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:playSong="@{playSong}"
            app:songActionHandler="@{songActionHandler}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Then this is the result:
[image]

Why there is top padding? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for several days, I found out that to fix this, the persistent bottom sheet layout container must be a `FrameLayout`. If not (like my case, I included the `NestedScrollView` direct and made it become a bottom sheet), it will contain the default top padding, and I still do not know why.

So here is my new Activity's xml layout code to fix:

```
<!-- [START] BottomSheet -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetMain"
        layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet_song"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
<!-- [END BottomSheet] -->
```

Hope this help you too.

Comment: @maoheing this cant be possible, it is working with linearlayout as well in my case.

Comment: For those that are facing this issue, the top padding observed in his example is the window system inset that is added automatically to specific views according to their hierarchy. In this case the top padding is the same height as the status bar, which in turn would be used to help show the content below it instead of behind it once the sheet is fully open.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your Activity manifest, apparently in my case it's the keyboard that cause the bottomsheet to automatically give padding.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the tag `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the root layout `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` of this view. Your source code layout will be like this.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

<!-- children contents -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Happened to me right now, removing the mentioned tag solved the issue.